# How to count values that are greater than or equal to the previous one

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset that produces a sinusoidal wave when put in a chart. Let us imagine that every day around 9AM, my chart hits the lowest point of the day and starts to go up. And around 6PM it reaches the highest point. I need to count (from 9AM to 6PM when my value is increasing) how many times my value is greater than or equal to the previous one and how many times my value is lesser than the previous one.

Let us take 11 values: [4-4-5-6-5-6-5-6-7-7-8]. I have 8 values that are greater than or equal to the previous one. And only 2 lesser that the previous one. The idea is to be able to say, during that period I have had 8 positive values for a progression of 4 (from 4 to 8). It means that on average, a positive value gives me 0.5.

**Important note: I am using BigQuery**

Here is my query so far:

```
select created_at,id,value,
(SELECT Count(value) from `dataset` where id LIKE "A1" AND value >= ?previous?) as positive,
(SELECT Count(value) from `dataset` where id LIKE "A1" AND value < ?previous?) as negative
from `dataset` 
where id LIKE "A1" 
AND value != 0 
AND DATETIME(created_at) BETWEEN PARSE_DATETIME("%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S", "20210505:09:00:00") AND PARSE_DATETIME("%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S", "20210505:17:59:59") 
order by created_at desc
```

here is an exemple of data. Id does not refer to the row but to the source of the data.

id |      created_at      | value

A1 | 2021-05-05 09:00:01  |  20

A1 | 2021-05-05 09:30:12  |  26

A1 | 2021-05-05 10:00:44  |  28

A1 | 2021-05-05 10:30:44  |  33

A1 | 2021-05-05 11:00:44  |  32

A1 | 2021-05-05 11:30:44  |  38

A1 | 2021-05-05 12:00:44  |  44

A1 | 2021-05-05 12:30:44  |  43

A1 | 2021-05-05 13:00:44  |  55

A1 | 2021-05-05 13:30:44  |  60

A1 | 2021-05-05 14:00:44  |  64

A1 | 2021-05-05 14:30:44  |  66

A1 | 2021-05-05 15:00:44  |  65

A1 | 2021-05-05 15:30:44  |  71

A1 | 2021-05-05 16:00:44  |  76

A1 | 2021-05-05 16:30:44  |  82

A1 | 2021-05-05 17:00:44  |  87

A1 | 2021-05-05 17:30:44  |  93

Comment: Can you share the sample inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [lag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag):

```
select id, sum(positive), sum(negative)
from (
  select
    created_at,
    id,
    value,
    if(value >= lag(value) over (order by created_at), 1, 0) as positive,
    if(value < lag(value) over (order by created_at), 1, 0) as negative
  from `dataset` 
  where id LIKE "A1" 
    AND value != 0 
    AND DATETIME(created_at) BETWEEN PARSE_DATETIME("%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S", "20210505:09:00:00") AND PARSE_DATETIME("%Y%m%d:%H:%M:%S", "20210505:17:59:59") 
  order by created_at desc
)
group by id
```

Comment: I have an error `Analytic function LAG cannot be called without an OVER clause at`. I am in BigQuery but I thought I could use every MySQL command...

Comment: oh, sorry, `over (order by created_at)` is mandatory

Comment: Ok great, thanks ! It's really close to what I need ! Is there a way add to the previous value ? To increment positive everytime instead of setting it to 1? Or to create another value to would SUM all positive values ?

Comment: The only way is to envelope everything with an aggregate query. Edited the answer.

Comment: Noice ! Exactly what I needed ! Many thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LAG](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) to add new column with value from preciding row.

Using which you can count the rows where current value is < or >= value from preciding row.

```
-- Dummy table
WITH table0 AS (
  SELECT 4 AS value, 1 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS value, 2 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS value, 3 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS value, 4 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS value, 5 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS value, 6 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS value, 7 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS value, 8 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS value, 9 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS value, 10 AS createdOn
  UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS value, 11 AS createdOn
)

-- SQL Query
SELECT
  COUNTIF(value >= prevValue) AS total_increase,
  COUNTIF(value < prevValue) AS total_decrease,
FROM (
  SELECT
    value, LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY createdOn) AS prevValue
  FROM table0
)
```